# how to reference organizational unit in home path[windows-server-2012]

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-administration

I have a windows 2012 R2, And I want to add home path for my users according to their respective ou i want it to look like this :
\WinServer-DC\sharingZone%ou%%username%
my AD Arch :
Site
->Department
->->user

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting the home path (profile folder path) by setting it to the hierarchical path for user object in active directory. You can create a network share drive which is always available to the active directory server and connect it as a share drive on the server and configure the directory structure as that of in active directory as below.

`CN=KarthikB,OU=TestOU1,DC=contoso,DC=com` – Active directory object path

`\\contoso\TestOU1\KarthkB` - home path directory structure
Please find below screenshot to set the home path for particular user in active directory .

[image]